# Reduce repetition of module.exports for functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6

I have 2 functions in index.js I do

```
module.exports.func1 = func1
module.exports.func2 = func2
```

then in somewhere I require them like this

```
const func1 = require('./index').func1
const func2 = require('./index').func2
```

Is there anyway to 'clean this up'? what if I have more functions then it will be quite messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in `index.js`:

```
var func = {
   func1 : func1,
   func2 : func2
};
module.exports = func;
```

And then require that using destructuring:

```
const {func1} = require('./index');
const {func2} = require('./index');
```

or single liner as,

```
const { func1, func2 } = require('./index');
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `module.exports` is an object, and because `require()` returns that object, you can destructure that object:

```
const { func1, func2 } = require('./index');
```

If you need to extract the properties into variable names *other* than the property names, you can follow the usual destructuring rules to rename while destructuring:

```
const { func1, func2: myFunc2 } = require('./index');
// use "func1" and "myFunc2" here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use curly bracket to destruct the object.

```
const { func1, func2 } = require('./index')
```

Or you can use a class or object and the func1, func2 will be a method or property into that class or object

```
function MyFunc () {
   this.func1 = function () {}
   this.func2 = function () {}
}

module.exports = new MyFunc()
```

or

```
var myFunc = {
   func1: function () {}
   func2: function () {}
}
module.exports = myFunc
```

Then you import like:

```
const myFunc = require("./index")
const func1 = myFunc.func1()
```

Answer (score 0):

for exporting functions you can export function in **index.js** as follows:

```js
module.exports = {
  func1: func1_def,
  func2: func2_def
};
```

Where **func1_def** & **func2_def** are function definitions.
You can import these functions as given below & use them directly.

```js
const { func1, func2 } = require('./index');
```

Answer (score 0):

To do the exports more simply, you can do:

```
module.exports = { func1, func2 }
```

To do the require more concisely you can do:

```
const { func1, func2 } = require('./index')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can export all your methods like this:

```
module.exports = {
  func1: () => {
    // logic
  },
  func2: () => {
    // logic
  },
}
```

And you can use then like below:

```
// import or require
const myMethods = require('./path/filename');

// call the method
myMethods.insertUser();
myMethods.loginAction();
myMethods.checkDuplicationID();
```